# Excel split string loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have 4 different ranges. I need to split the contents of these ranges. so the cell contains;
Tom Jerry Bugs Bunny Jack Sparrow Bob. And I want to split that into 7 different cells. I have looked on the internet and have discover how to perform a split like this with the following code.

```
Dim text As String
Dim a As Integer
Dim name As Variant
text = ActiveCell.Value
name = Split(text, " ")
For a = 0 To UBound(name)
Cells(1, a + 1).Value = name(a)
Next a
```

My issue is i need this inside a loop so it will go through a range, say ("H1:H200") and this is were I am stuck, I have started the loop, but cannot get the split to work inside it. Here is the start of my loop:

```
Dim rCell As Range
Dim rRng As Range

Set rRng = Range("H1:H200")
For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
 'split string here.
```

Any help on this issue would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why reinvent the wheel? You could just use [`TextToColumns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193593%28v=office.14%29.aspx). For example:

```
Dim rCell As Range
Dim rRng As Range

Set rRng = Range("H1:H200")
For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
    rCell.TextToColumns Destination:=rCell.Offset(0, 1), Space:=True
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the For inside the For. Something like,

```
Dim txtStr As String
Dim aCtr As Integer
Dim nameVar() As String
Dim rCell As Range
Dim rRng As Range

Set rRng = Range("H1:H200")
For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
    txtStr = rCell.Value
    nameVar = Split(txtStr, " ")
    For aCtr = 0 To UBound(nameVar)
        Cells(1, aCtr + 1).Value = nameVar(aCtr)
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Came to this conclusion in the end on my own, thanks for the answers though

```
Dim bb As Integer
Dim text As String
Dim aa As Integer
Dim name As Variant
Dim cc As Range
Dim rng As Range
bb = 2
Set rng = Range("H2:H200")
For Each cc In rng
 text = cc.Value
 name = Split(text, " ")
 For aa = 0 To UBound(name)
 'Ubound finds the end of an array
 Cells(bb, aa + 1).Value = name(aa)
Next aa
```

bb = bb + 1
Next